# How to run a php script in a rails application

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Running on rails 4.2.1
Having trouble on where to include a contact_me.php script 
The contact page is created in the homepage.html.erb file

Here's what it looks like:

```
  <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Me</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Shoot me an email if you like what you see! My schedule is flexible and my door is always open.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
```

And Here's what the contact_me.php looks like:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!!!

Comment: Why don't you just recreate this functionality in rails?

Comment: I used bootstrap and created a rails app. I'm also not that rails savvy.

Answer (score 1):

To run a PHP script you will need php support in the web server or at least `php-cli` installed in your web server.

If you have this kind of support you could do:

**a)** Publish your script to a public endpoint like `public/script.php`. And send a POST to this endpoint.

**b)** If you don't have support for public endpoints, you could write a Ruby endpoint that executes the php script as [a shell command](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html) in the server side. So you could do something like: `php script.php ARGUMENTS`. But you will need to change the script a little bit to receive the Args, and also create the Ruby public endpoint.

If you don't have a Server that supports PHP, I think this could be a little bit complicated. I will **recommend** you to port that script to Ruby since is easier to maintain code written in one programming language at a time.